Is there a way to disable hardhat forking via CLI?
I have the following in my hardhat.config.js
networks: {
  hardhat: {
    forking: {
         url: `https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/${ALCHEMY_API_KEY}`,
         blockNumber: 14390000
    }
  }
}

When I run npx hardhat test, it will fork the network instead of using a local hardhat node. Is there any way I can enable/disable forking when running npx hardhat test in CLI?

Running npx hardhat test without a specified network runs the test against the hardhat network. And in this case, the hardhat network is configured to be a fork.
You can use the reset() function of the network helper plugin (docs) to remove the fork state during runtime.
const { loadFixture, reset } = require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers");

describe.only('Test group', function () {
    async function deployFixture() {
        console.log(`Block number non-zero before reset: ${await ethers.provider.getBlockNumber()}`);
        await reset();
        console.log(`Block number zero after reset: ${await ethers.provider.getBlockNumber()}`);
        return;
    }
  
    it('runs the test case', async function () {
        await loadFixture(deployFixture);
    });
});


Note: If you want to run the test against a different network (configured in your hardhat.config.js), you can specify the --network option:
npx hardhat test --network "myOtherNetwork"

